# LongListSelector with ContextMenu

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, contextmenu, longlistselector

I am actually trying to implement a ContextMenu in a LongListSelector in my Windows Phone 8 app.
This is what I am doing. I can't understand why the context menu is not showed at all. How do I make it work? :/

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="Storico" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="384" Margin="39,254,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="406" BorderBrush="#FFFF2800" Tap="Storico_Tap">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="420" Height="40" Foreground="#FFFF9000" FontSize="30" ManipulationStarted="TextBlock_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="TextBlock_ManipulationCompleted"/>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu" >
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Watch" Header="Watch Trailer"/>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Buy" Header="Buy"/>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Share" Header="Share"/>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried adding ContextMenu to TextBlock?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="420" Height="40" Foreground="#FFFF9000" FontSize="30" ManipulationStarted="TextBlock_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="TextBlock_ManipulationCompleted">
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu" >
            <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Watch" Header="Watch Trailer"/>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Buy" Header="Buy"/>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Share" Header="Share"/>
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks man! As much as your solution looks "simple", that's what actually worked. I had already tried it, I don't know why it hadn't worked before. Thanks again! :)